# Hallar los numero pares e impares de un digito en C++

Tags: c++

Mi programa debe pedir un numero mínimo de 5 dígitos e imprimir los números pares e impares en dos grupos, además deben imprimirse en el mismo orden que están en el número, por ejemplo:

```
Input:
1234567
Output:
Numero con dígitos pares 246
Numero con dígitos impares 1357
```

Pero hasta ahora solo he logrado imprimir los números en total:

```
int main ()
{
int n = 0 ,tem = 0 ;
int div=1;
cin>> n;

tem=n;

while (tem/10 != 0)
{
  tem = tem/10;
  div = div*10;
}
while (div!=0)
{
  cout << n/div;
  if (div/10!=0)
  {
    cout<<",";
  }
  n=n%div;
  div=div/10;
  }
  cout<<"\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Ya les enseñaron a usar matrices para almacenar varios datos?
Otro tema, creo que te estas liando mucho, veo que usas el operador %, que como sabrás devuelve el resto de una división. Entonces, si numero%2 da 0, es par, si no, impar, con esto deberías poder hacer un código mucho mas simple.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Exactamente que quieres que te agamos los deveres?
Te recomiendo que rebises la teoria de arrays.

En su dia, segui este curso de programacion en C y creo que explica perfectamente lo que necesitas para poder programar tu ejercicio.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SnwmweCMUTA&t=209s&ab_channel=EmpiezaAProgramar

Comment: 2 aportes has hecho hoy, y los 2 son ejercicios básicos de programación en C.
Estamos a inicio de curso, tú mismo. 
Si utilizaras el buscador de stackoverflow verías que existen ya distintos posts con la misma problemática.
¡Para terminar, te vuelvo a recomendar que le eches una ojeada al curso que te pase de YouTube y que repases la teoría básica!

Comment: Primero hoy no , ayer sí. Segundo será porque recién estoy comenzado.

Comment: Le recomiendo además que se lea las normas comunitarias.

Answer (score 1):

Mi solución es transformar el valor entero en su representación de string, para luego recorrerla de izquierda a derecha (digito más significativo a menos significativo).

Con eso puedo ir examinando cada elemento e imprimiendolo de inmediato, sin necesidad de almacenamiento intermedio:

```
int main() {
    int n = 0, temp = 0;
    char digitos[20];
    
    cin >> n;
    sprintf(digitos, "%d", n);

    cout << "Pares: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(digitos); i++) {
        if (int(digitos[i]) % 2 == 0) cout << digitos[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << "\nImpares: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(digitos); i++) {
        if (int(digitos[i]) % 2 == 1) cout << digitos[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola, lo estaba probando pero me podías explicar que es strlen porque me sale error.

Answer (score 0):

El código es muy simple, tú estás pensando en coger los pares de un int de input, y eso es muy complicado, si lo piensas bien, puedes usar un std::string para almacenar el input y con std::stoi() convertir el std::string a int, lo que hace mucho más fácil el código. Y con un simple for loop (sería mejor un for each. . .) voy convirtiendo cada char del std::string a int y mediante el operando módulo compruebo si es par, si es par lo añado al std::string de evenNums y si no es par lo añado al std::string de oddNums.

Posible solución:

```
#include <iostream> // std::stoi() y otras
#include <cstdlib>  // printf()    y otras
#include <cstring> // strlen()     y otras

int main()
{
    std::string inUser, oddNums, evenNums, strTpm; // odd es Impar y even PAR
    int tmpInt;

    do
    {
        printf("Input: \n");
        std::cin >> inUser;  // scanf no soporta la clase std::string 
        
    }while(strlen(inUser.c_str()) < 5);  // para que se repita mientras el input no sea de 5 cifras


    for (unsigned i = 0; i < strlen(inUser.c_str()); i++)
    {
        strTpm = inUser[i];  // string temporal para almacenar el char actual
        tmpInt = std::stoi(strTpm); // convertir el string temporal a int

        if (tmpInt % 2 == 0 )
        {
            evenNums += inUser[i]; // Añado a pares si el módulo es 0
        }
        else
            oddNums += inUser[i];  // Añado a impares si el módulo no es 0
    }

    printf("Output:\nPares: %s\nImpares: %s\n", evenNums.c_str(), oddNums.c_str()); // Printf y scanf son el doble de rápidos que cout y cin


    return 0;
}
```

Si tienes alguna duda del código puedes preguntar

Comment: Hola, si en caso quiero que en caso q no haya números pares o impares aparezca el 0?

Comment: Los números son pares o impares,no hay números que no sean ni pares ni impares. Si metiese unos chars o string el programa daría error porque std::stoi no podría realizar la conversión.